# R- Make a word cloud from column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, word-cloud

How can I make a word cloud from a column in my dataframe (it contains some english words)?

Which package should I download?

And how do I safe the image as either a jpeg or png file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google with these terms

```
word cloud r-project package
```

will give you at least three packages on the first page:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggwordcloud/vignettes/ggwordcloud.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html

Which package you should use depends on what you exactly need. Since you mentioned that your data is organised in a data frame, I recommend that you start looking at ggwordcloud. It works with data frames and, usually, plots based on ggplot are prettier.

For further details, please refer to the documentation of the package. If you have any trouble with that, you are welcome to ask. But some of the examples are quite self-explanatory and you shouldn't have any trouble with them.